# Can I initiate a Tk Variable before I start my Tk widgets and windows?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a global dictionary of data from which I will display various data in my dictionary. Two elements of the dictionary are a list and a Boolean Variable. I want to use the BooleanVar() in a CheckButton widget.

The dictionary is to store information from various machine subsystems that I want to display in my gui. One function of the gui is to be able to exclude a channel if the user wishes, meaning stop monitoring.
The machine channel is the dictionary key, with a list and a boolean varaible. The list is contains some initial data to determine the status of the channel. The BooleanVar() I want to add to a checkbutton so the user can toggle between excluding/including the channel gui.

```
channelListFull = {'sys1:channel1': (['Label1', 'GOOD', 0, 0],BooleanVar()),
                   'sys1:channel2': (['Label2', 'GOOD', 0, 0],BooleanVar()),
                   'sys2:channel1': (['Label3', 'GOOD', 0, 0],BooleanVar())
etc...
```

The rest of the code (roughly, not exactly executable) is as follows

```
class ChannelDisplay(Frame)
    def __init__(self, master=None, label='NONE', channel='NONE',**kw):
        Frame.__init(self, master, **kw)

        self.lbl = label
        self.chnl = channel

        self.component = tk.Label(self, text=self.lbl)
        self.component.grid
        self.toggle = tk.Checkbutton(self,variable=channelListFull[channel][1])
        self.toggle.grid

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.monitoring()

   def monitor(self):
        channelRemoveList = []
        for entry in channelListFull.keys():
            badChannel = channelListFull[entry][1].get()
            if not badChannel :
                channelRemoveList.append(entry) #This is a separate function   
                                                 that modifies which channels 
                                                 are included in the monitoring 
                                                 process

        for entry in channelListFull.keys():
            self.chan = ChannelDisplay(root,label=channelListFull[0][0],channel=entry)
            self.chan.grid()

root = Tk()
app=application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

I get the error at the line where I create `channelListFull` saying:

```
 Exception AttributeError: "BooleanVar instance has no attribute '_tk'" in 
<bound method BooleanVar.__del__ of <Tkinter.BooleanVar instance at 0x7f39981b77e8>> 
ignored
```

Comment: Maybe use some wrapper that lazily creates a variable of the specified type once it's needed? But what is the problem with initializing `root = Tk()` before creating the dictionary?

Comment: `BooleanVar` & friends are not actually Python objects; they live in a specific instance of the Tcl/Tk interpreter, the Python object is just a proxy to the actual var.  Normally, you create such an instance by calling `Tk()`; one will be created automatically for you in some cases (that I'm not entirely clear on), but that's dangerous to rely on because it becomes all too easy to have widgets/images/vars/etc. that live in separate instances and therefore cannot work together.

Comment: You must call `Tk()` to initialize Tkinter _before_ creating any Tkinter variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I initiate a Tk Variable before I start my Tk widgets and windows?

No, you cannot. You must create a root window first.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. Not what I was hoping for, but back to the drawing board on how to keep track of this on/off switch.